# 2 servers and only one way traffic

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-sbs

This has me stumped...

I've got an old war horse SBS 2003 server and a server that is a few months old running Server 2008 R2 (Don't ask me why they put 2008 on it when it's so new...).

The 2003 server is the domain controller and is being replaced soon and I'm trying to bring the 2008 server into the fold as the DNS, DHCP and application server.

Last night something went wrong with the 2003 server. There was an 'exceeded licensing error' warning that popped up and it felt a bit unstable so I gave it a reboot and it's all down hill from there. Nothing worked when I rebooted. 30 clients are unable to access any mapped drives or UNC paths. DHCP isn't functioning etc.

I managed to find a Microsoft auto backup of the license key and reset it, which worked. It's now listing the key and reporting the number of licenses etc. but nothing works still. It's like someone hit a big red button and it can't be taken back. I've rebooted this server about 10 times so far to no avail.

The 2003 server is on 10.1.1.10 and the 2008 server is 10.1.1.15, both servers can access the internet so the DNS and gateway is fine. 2003 server can access a UNC path on the 2008 server but not the other way around. The 2008 server simply cannot ping or connect to the 2003 server. I'm trying to setup DNS and DHCP on 2008 so the users can function but it can't authorize because it can't contact the 2003 server domain controller.

I'm at a loss. There's no anti-virus on 2008 server but there is one on 2003 but I don't think this is the issue. It's not a security suite, it's a simple out of date and not functioning standard AV.

Firewalls are disabled on both servers. There is a Sonicwall on the gateway at 10.1.1.25 but I can't imagine that is stopping any traffic, nothing has been changed since this server started playing up. I'm new to Sonicwalls but I can't see anything obvious.

Here's the ipconfigs.

```
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server2003
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : Domain.local
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Domain.local

Ethernet adapter Network Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Domain.local
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-2B-2B-4B-04-4A
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.10
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.25
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.15
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Server Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-2B-2B-4B-04-4C
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : No
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
```

The second adapter has nothing connected to it, hence the empty details. It was originally disabled when the server was working but my boss wanted to activate it...

And, here's the ipconfig for server 2008

```
Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server2008
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : Domain.local
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Domain.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Domain.local
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-A6-5E-DE
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.15(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.25
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.15
Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.15
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9BF5353E-E08B-4415-9EA2-9DF221F8D8FF}:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Domain.local
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Now that I've posted those I see some pretty obvious differences with NetBIOS over TCPIP, Node Type and WINS Proxy enabled etc. I just don't know enough about it to make an educated guess.

Any help or thoughts would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!